# Can I get a Facebook authorization that won't expire?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I want the users of my website to be able to authorize Facebook access in their profiles, such that our servers can continuously use that authorization. I know how to do the authorization part, but what I get back is an access key that will eventually expire. This would require the user to log back in and re-authorize us periodically.

Is there a way that the user can grant authorization once, giving me an access key that won't expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

The `offline_access` is now disabled as pointed out in one of the comments. To understand the changes Facebook as a nice post. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

#### Old Answer

> If the application has not requested offline_access permission, the access token is time-bounded. Time-bounded access token also get invalidated when the user logs out of Facebook. **If the application has obtained offline_access permission from the user, the access token does not have an expiry.** However it gets invalidated whenever the user changes his/her password.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Great, that sounds exactly what I need. Do you happen to know the name of the URL parameter that I pass that value to? I can't find it anywhere on the graph API site.

Comment: @Mike: I guess it is `offline_access`, more at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: That's the value, but what parameter do I assign it to? Unfortunately, there isn't more at that link, which is frustrating. They just say "use offline_access", but there's no information as to How to use it. Do I just declare the parameter and assign no value? Hmm...

Comment: @Mike: That's what I thought. :)

Comment: offline_access is deprecated.

Comment: @Cthulhu Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer with a link to FB's post explaining the change.